# Client-side validation based on models with Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, validation

I just want to use jQuery validation to show "real-time" errors for the user. The point is: I don't want to have a duplex-direction (client-side/server-side) validation for maintenance purposes.

So I ask: there's a way to communicate jQuery validation to ask just for the model's validation that is provided by Rails?

Or even better: we don't need to use jQuery validation specifically. Just tell me another/better way to solve my problem smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this would be by creating a function in your controller that responds to JS requests. In that function you validate the data with the model and respond with any errors (which you can then process in JQuery).